# Hide bookmark bar in Chrome new tab

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

In the Chrome browser, I know that I can show or hide bookmark bar by Ctrl+Shift+B.

But if I open a new tab, the bookmark bar appears again. This bookmark bar disappears when I access any website.
Can I always hide this bookmark bar even in a new tab?
(I want my Google account logged-in.)

Answer (score 1):

Installing any Chrome extension that overrides the "new tab" behavior will achieve your desired result of not displaying the bookmark toolbar, even when you open a new tab.

Comment: [Momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=en) is a good example of such an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I use [New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) which provides the functionality you want.

[image: New Tab Redirect]